# Parsing HTML with HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Tags: html, perl, xpath

I have many HTML documents that I need to parse. Here's an example of the data so that I can explain myself a little better

```xml
<div id="filerDiv">
    <div class="mailer">Mailing Address
        <span class="mailerAddress">65 MARKET STREET, SUITE 1207,</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">CAMANA BAY, P.O. BOX 31110</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">GRAND CAYMAN E9 KY1-1205</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mailer">Business Address
        <span class="mailerAddress">65 MARKET STREET, SUITE 1207,</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">CAMANA BAY, P.O. BOX 31110</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">GRAND CAYMAN E9 KY1-1205</span>
        <span class="mailerAddress">345 943 4573</span>
    </div>
    <div class="companyInfo">
        <span class="companyName">GREENLIGHT CAPITAL RE, LTD. (Filer)
            <acronym title="Central Index Key">CIK</acronym>: <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=0001385613&amp;action=getcompany">0001385613 (see all company filings)</a></span>
        <p class="identInfo"><acronym title="Internal Revenue Service Number">IRS No.</acronym>: <strong>000000000</strong><br />Type: <strong>10-Q</strong> | Act: <strong>34</strong> | File No.: <a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?filenum=001-33493&amp;action=getcompany"><strong>001-33493</strong></a> | Film No.: <strong>161612131</strong><br /><acronym title="Standard Industrial Code">SIC</acronym>: <b><a href="/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&amp;SIC=6331&amp;owner=include">6331</a></b> Fire, Marine &amp; Casualty Insurance<br />Assistant Director 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to grab the four `span` elements which follow the second `div` element with the class `mailer`.  Here is the code I have so far

```perl
my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
$root->parse($content);
my @Baddress = $root->findvalue('//div[@id="filerDiv"]/div[@class="mailer"][2]/span/text()');
```

But when I print out the contents of `@Baddress` all of the `span` text is displayed on one line, like this

```
65 MARKET STREET, SUITE 1207,CAMANA BAY, P.O. BOX 31110 GRAND CAYMAN E9 KY1-1205 345 943 4573
```

Everything is being assigned to a single array element. I would like each `span` to be assigned to its own array element so that they may be parsed individually.

Answer (score 0):

Uhg after hours of slaving over this I missed 1 essential element.  The code needs to be as such

```
my @Baddress = $root->findvalues('//div[@id="filerDiv"]/div[@class="mailer"][2]/span/text()');
```

I simply had $root->findvalue which was assigning everything to 1 variable.  Stupid mistake

Comment: I think you still have an unnecessarily complex XPath expression and your code could be improved substantially

Comment: could you elaborate?